# Animate camera based off selected object like in viewport

Tags: camera

hopefully the title isn't too confusing.

I want to animate a camera. And i want it to pivot around an object- like when you select an object in the regular viewport. Here is a gif trying to explain:
[Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/nGcDv2o.gifv)

In the gif, i am looking thru the camera, and have the cylinder selected, and am pivoting off that selected object, and seeing it thru the camera as well. I want to press record, and then animate based off how i am explaining this, then smooth the keys after recording.

I have tried using emptys, different pivot methods by pressing the period key and some parenting stuff, but cant quite get it.

Is this possible?